# Как правильно разобрать ответ сервера retrofit android?

Tags: android

У меня уже много есть вопросов которые связанны одним не очень большим проектом, у тех кто большинство их видел начала вырисовываться общая картинка всей программы, но у меня возникла одна сложность во время работы с ответами сервера. Логика на сервере максимально проста и не требует проверки, все завязано на правильности запроса и его параметров. Мое приложение довольно активно общается с сервером, получает и отправляет данные. Весь процесс общения приложения с сервером сводится к тому что я что-то запрашиваю и сервер присылает ответ, и этот ответ может быть как удовлетворительным (200) так и неудовлетворительным (400,401,403). В первом случае я уже вроде разобрался, как и что создавать, и как вытаскивать из ответа сервера нужные мне данные, но вот я не очень понимаю как уточнять неудовлетворительный ответ. Вот например мне приходит с сервера такой ответ:

```
Code: 400 Bad Request 
Content: {
    "error_code": 7, 
    "message": "no_token_given"
}
```

или такой:

```
Code: 401 Unauthorized
Content: {
    "error_code": 8, 
    "message": "refresh_token_expired"
}
```

короче куча вариантов есть. Данный вопрос был задан для того что-бы понять как программа будет понимать какой негативный ответ пришел, ведь он один из многих. На данный момент я хочу решить проблему с протуханием access_token, для того что-бы его обновить мне нужно отправить запрос на обновление токена, а для того что-бы отправить такой запрос нужно получить предварительно такой ответ:

```
Code: 401 Unauthorized
Content: {
    "error_code": 3, 
    "message": "access_token_expired"
}
```

в моей коде все вроде как понятно, есть onResponce или onFailure, но я не могу понять в какой из этих функций нужно обрабатывать негативные ответы, что-бы когда приходит ответ за токен, я смог отправить свой запрос на новый. Если кто-то понял суть моего вопроса и может мне помочь, то я буду очень рад услышать ваше мнение.

Comment: Если вас правильно понимаю, вам нужно знать код ошибки для дальнейшей обработки?

Comment: да Вы все верно поняли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Call<JsonData> call = lAPI.getData();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonData> call, Response<JsonData> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                // ...
            } else {
                // Обрабатываем ошибку
                ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorBody.string(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonData> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Что-то пошло не так",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: я так понял, теперь нужно просто переганять `errorBody` в string и искать вхождение подстроки в строку, то есть прогнать все ошибки?

Comment: `errorBody.string()` хранит код ошибки получаемый от сервера